# Form.ShowDialog changes the height of a label control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a dialog box in VB.NET from certain elements. I have options to have a label, one or more buttons, a text box, and/or a combobox. I use the BuildForm() procedure to calculate the size of all the elements to fit correctly. Once that is done, I use Form.ShowDialod() to display it, but I've found that my controls are not retaining their sizes. Specifically a Label control that had been calculated to fit its text goes from 115px to 92px.

It is anchored to the form, but even without resizing the form at all, the control changes size. In this example, I can see that lblDsc.height changed from 115 to 92.

What can be causing this and how do I mitigate it? I thought calculating the controls beforehand would be straightforward.

```
Public Function MyInputButtonBox(ByVal description As String, title As String, ParamArray buttons As String()) As Integer
    If buttons.Length = 0 Then Return -1
    inpBox = Nothing
    BuildForm(description, buttons)
    inpForm.Text = title
    MsgBox(lblDsc.Height)
    inpForm.ShowDialog()
    MsgBox(lblDsc.Height)
    Return inpForm.Tag
    inpForm.Dispose()
End Function
```

For more context, here is the portion of BuildForm that calculates lblDsc's attributes. Note that AutoSize is set to False and I moved the anchoring code to the end after the form size had been finalized.

```
    'Description
    lblDsc.AutoSize = False
    lblDsc.Top = 5
    lblDsc.Left = 5
    lblDsc.Width = btnPanel.Left - lblDsc.Left - 5
    lblDsc.Text = description
    Dim textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(lblDsc.Text, New Font(lblDsc.Font.FontFamily, lblDsc.Font.Size, lblDsc.Font.Style), lblDsc.Size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak)
    lblDsc.Height = Math.Ceiling(1.1 * textSize.Height)
    lblDsc.Parent = inpForm
    lblDsc.Visible = True
    'lblDsc.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left + AnchorStyles.Top + AnchorStyles.Right + AnchorStyles.Bottom
    lblDsc.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle 'BorderStyle.None  'TODO restore no border after testing
```

Comment: Try setting the size manually to what you want

Comment: 115/92 = 125%, [a magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e).  If you need dpi virtualization for some reason then put the bottom snippet in the Load event handler of the form.

Comment: `lblDsc.AutoSize = false;` maybe?